# Objective c - Slide an image/filter over an image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

I am trying to slide a filter, or an image with a filter applied, over another image. I have included a video of what I am trying to do [Snap chat filter example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwuE8fdsLlAhOUd2dTlLWGt1UU0/view?usp=sharing)

Currently I have a UIView with the original image (self.mainImage.image), and I create a filter with the following code:

```
- (void)applyBWFilter {
    UIImage *img = [_images peak];

    // Add B&W filter
    // Create image rectangle with current image width/height
    CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, img.size.width, img.size.height);

    // Grayscale color space
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();

    // Create bitmap content with current image size and grayscale colorspace
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(nil, img.size.width, img.size.height, 8, 0, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaNone);

    // Draw image into current context, with specified rectangle
    // using previously defined context (with grayscale colorspace)
    CGContextDrawImage(context, imageRect, [img CGImage]);

    // Create bitmap image info from pixel data in current context
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);

    // Create a new UIImage object
    self.mainImage.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];

    // Release colorspace, context and bitmap information
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    CGContextRelease(context);
    CFRelease(imageRef);
}
```

How can I get the new image to slide over the old image like the example?

Comment: have you find any solution for this? i also want to implement same filter.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to do this. Probably the easiest would be to generate the replacement image first. Then install it in an image view and put it on top of the existing image view. Add a CAShapeLayer that's the same size as your new, filtered image as the mask layer of your "filter applied" image view. Start with the shape layer empty. Add an opaque rectangle UIBezierPath's CGPath as the shape in the shape layer, but have the rectangle's position shifted off-screen so it's not visible.

Finally, animate a change to the shape layer were you move the rectangle path to fill the contents of the image.

The empty shape layer will completely mask the image to start with. When you animate the opaque rectangle shape into place, it will reveal your filtered image as it animates into view.